# Scala: Type Mismatch error when passing argument based on the same type

Tags: scala, apache-spark, implicit

I have a basic scala issue:

I defined a custom function to add to Dataset[Row] that lets me create my own WrappedDataset and used an implicit function to achieve that:

```
class CustomFunctions(dataset: Dataset[Row]) {
  def wrap(): WrappedDataset = {
    new WrappedDataset(
      inputDf = dataset,
    )
  }
}

object CustomFunctions {
  implicit def addWrap(dataset: Dataset[Row]): CustomFunctions = new CustomFunctions(dataset)
}
```

I also am using this case object to expose a case class for use here:

```
case object Singleton extends NRC {
  def apply(x: TupleExpr): BagExpr = Singleton(x)
}
```

Now when using this in practice i am having issues with type mismatch: (Bear in mind the flatMap function here is a custom one here that takes a (f: TupleExpr => BagExpr) as an argument -> the issue is with the argument of the Singleton() call)

```
val ds: Dataset[Row] = simpleStringObject()
val e1: WrappedDataset = ds.wrap()
e1.flatMap(x => Singleton(x))
```

On the final line I get the error:

> Type mismatch. Required: Singleton.TupleExpr, found: e1.TupleExpr

TupleExpr is the same for both of these in practice so why has Scala decided it is a type mismatch?

EDIT:
I should add that one quick fix is to case as the correct instance type like so:

```
e1.flatMap(x => Singleton(x.asInstanceOf[Singleton.TupleExpr]))
```

But this isn't an appropriate solution as I want to get to the root of the issue instead of casting each time.

EDIT2:

TupleExpr is just a trait that extends the trait Expr and mixes in another trait AbstractTuple:

```
trait TupleExpr extends Expr with AbstractTuple {
  def tp: TupleType
}
```

Comment: You didn't show us how is `TupleExpr` defined.

Comment: @GaëlJ I added an edit with TupleExpr definition

Comment: Where is it defined? Inside something else? Also please show the `flatMap` definition. Provide the whole code as is and not small separated pieces.

Comment: @GaëlJ It is a trait defined in the NRC package that both the Singleton class and the main class with the e1.flatMap code extend